# Concurrent output from java application to elasticsearch

Tags: java, multithreading, elasticsearch

I am researching if it is possible to have multiple threads output to elasticsearch concurrently using the transport client and bulk upload apis. Specifically, I want to have multiple transport clients or bulk upload api instances run on their own threads and handle input to elasticsearch. My specific reason for wanting to do this is so I can create a load balancing algorithm to handle a very large number of json messages efficiently. I have been googling for some time and can't find any documentation on this type of thing, or anyone else asking similar questions. Additionally, I am new to elasticsearch. Does anyone have any insight on this, some literature they could share, or a good place to start? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea on how you can achieve this is to have a static class that acts as a wrapper for an elastic Client object.  You can then spawn several threads in whatever code you are executing using the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  The ExecutorService includes many utility methods, detailed in the link, that might help you manage your processing.  These threads would then call into the static class to get the client object when doing processing, prepare their bulk requests, and then send them.

If you are lazy, you can just have loops that execute indefinitely and have sleep calls to help prevent overloading.

A few caveats to watch out for:

1) Be very mindful of Elasticsearch's [Thread pool and queue sizes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html).  Do not submit data to ES faster than your hardware can handle.  If you are submitting data to ES too fast such that you are overloading the queue, bulk requests will be aborted.  Do not increase the bulk queue size unless you need to and know your hardware can keep up and prevent overload.  Increasing the queue size if you are running into roadblocks will only delay the inevitable.  If you are overloading the bulk, include a way to throttle requests in your code.

2) Partition up your bulk requests by type/index.  I am not 100% sure how ES handles bulk requests under the hood, but I have noticed some inconsistent behavior in the queue size when shoving tons requests to different indexes in one bulk request.  It would make sense that Elasticsearch partitions up the requests to prevent tons of useless seqs and optimize shard/node traversal, but I have noticed that the queue size goes up much quicker if you mix.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am going to give this a try and I'll post what I come up with.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I will post again if I find this is an optimal solution.